# Variable selection multiple data types

Tags: dataset, multicollinearity, ranks

I'm working on a data set containing 45 predictors that cover metric, ordinal and nominal variables. Aiming to finally build a model, which explains the interacting effect of a set of predictor variables on a single response variable, I'm initially seeking for an objective way to reduce the data set's dimensionality according to the collinearity/association between the predictor variables -something like the VIF, but with the ability to test for collinearity between all kind of data types.